# How to add TXT records when registering service using NSD api in android?

Tags: android, networking, mdns

I am trying to register a service using NSD api in android but i am not sure how to add TXT records?

Answer (score 1):

From the Android 5.0 it should be so:

```
...
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    serviceInfo.setAttribute("yourkey", yourString);
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:
The NSD api still does not support adding TXT Record.
I worked out a solution by porting jMDNS it is a simple java implementation and supports almost all the features on mDNS.